# Getting "Value does not fall withint the expected range" when calling to Frame.GoBack

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm creating a Windows Universal Application that uses Navigation (via Frames).

I want to create a reusable `Page` to avoid creating multiple pages. The idea is to use the same `Page` over and over (the same type, not the same instance).

In order to get different content shown in each navigation, I just pass the content of the page inside the parameters of a `Frame.Navigate` call, like this:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(ReusablePage), myContent);
```

To illustrate my idea. I've created a very simple, minimal, reproducible example of my proof-of-concept UWP app. The problem is that it throws and I don't know why. This is the code:

*(see the exact problem near the end of the post)*

## MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Navigate" Tapped="Navigate" />
        <Button Content="Go back" Tapped="GoBack" IsEnabled="False" x:Name="BackButton" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyFrame" />
</Grid>
```

## MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace App4
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private int times = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GoBack(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                MyFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }

        private void Navigate(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(ReusablePage), new Button() { Content = $"Navigated {++times} times"});
            BackButton.IsEnabled = MyFrame.CanGoBack;
        }
    }
}
```

## ReusablePage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App4.ReusablePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</Page>
```

## ReusablePage.xaml.cs

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App4
{
    public sealed partial class ReusablePage : Page
    {
        public ReusablePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            Content = (UIElement) e.Parameter;
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
    }
}
```

To reproduce the problem:

1. Run the application
2. click on the Navigate button until the Go
   back button becomes enabled
3. Click on the "Go back" button (click twice, at least).
4. You should get a `System.ArgumentException`

> Value does not fall within the expected range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this code to the `ReusablePage` constructor.

```cs
public ReusablePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
}
```

At the same time, you can also use `e.NavigationMode` to determine the way to navigate to the page.

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        // Do something.
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Your error occurred when rendering the visual tree. There is no more detailed explanation of the error, but the cache page can effectively solve this problem.

Best regards.

Comment: The thing is that e.Parameter is never null. It comes with the very same instance of Button the page was navigated with when navigating forward.

Comment: Please, test the code. You will see it for yourself.

Comment: I forgot to say that Page.Content can be set to null :) That's not the problem.

Comment: @SuperJMN I apologize for my immature answer, please check my updated answer, after the cache page, it works fine.

Comment: Richard, don't worry! You have demonstrated that you took your time. That is important. What I would like to know is why the error happens. What's wrong when the NavigationCacheMode is not enabled? Is the control that comes in e.Parameter marked as "expired" in some way?

Comment: thanks for your encouragement. This error may be caused by a control conflict. When backing up, the button represented by `e.Parameter` and the button that should be displayed on the page are the same, which may cause the application to not correctly judge the updated content when updating the UI. So from a rational point of view, I recommend passing data parameters instead of control parameters, such as passing `times` instead of passing a `Button`.

Comment: "passing data parameters instead of UI instances" :) that's sounds reasonable, but as I mention above, my goal is to create a "Reusable" Page. For me, Pages are just wrappers for content that is shown via navigation. I have determined that if I want to navigate to a view, I could create a Page dynamically and inject the content (usually a complex UserControl) instead of creating a bunch of Pages that only containt a single UserControl. It provides a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Please, take a look to the actual Navigation system I've created to see what I mean. It uses a IoC-DI container and ViewModel-based navigation. https://github.com/SuperJMN/Parrot-Reflight/blob/master/Reflight.Gui/Navigation.cs

Comment: I understand your thoughts, but passing controls that have been rendered into VisualTree is not a good way. You can try to put the process of creating a control in the Page and render it into different controls based on the incoming data.

Comment: Do you mean, to pass a Func<UIElement>? (a factory)

Comment: I mean putting the factory that created the UIElement in the `ReusablePage` and passing only the data. It’s like just passing the parts and assembling them at the destination.